# SQL Server 2008 replication failing with: process could not execute 'sp_replcmds'

Tags: sql-server-2008, replication

I have an issue with SQL replication that I am having trouble fixing.  What I am doing is restoring two DBs from a production backup, and then installing replication between them.  The replication seems to be configured without any errors, but when I look at the status I see error messages like this:

> Error messages:
>
> The process could not execute
>   'sp_replcmds' on 'MYSERVER1'. Get
>   help: http://help/MSSQL_REPL20011
>
> Cannot execute as the database
>   principal because the principal "dbo"
>   does not exist, this type of principal
>   cannot be impersonated, or you do not
>   have permission. (Source: MSSQLServer,
>   Error number: 15517) Get help:
>   http://help/15517
>
> The process could not execute 'sp_replcmds' on 'MYSERVER1'.
>   Get help: http://help/MSSQL_REPL22037

What does this mean?

Answer (score 67):

When I had this problem, my database didn't have an owner set properly. I had restored a database from another windows domain, right clicked the database -> properties and verified in the "general" tab that the owner was set correctly. However, in the "files" tab, owner was not set at all. As soon as I set it, replication was running without problems.

Answer (score 27):

'dbo' maps to a login that is invalid. If you run `select suser_sname(owner_sid) from sys.databases`, you probaly get NULL for those two DBs. You need to change 'dbo' to a valid login. Run, on both databases:

```
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::[<dbname>] TO [sa]
```

Comment: Doing that will change the owner of the DB to sa, which I don't want.  The owner of the DB is currently my personal account, and I want it to stay that way.  Could I just re-associate dbo somehow?

Comment: You can associate it to any account you want, but it has to be a valid NT account. Does suser_sname(owner_sid) return NULL? Then is an invalid account and you *must* change it.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

The easiest way to correct the error is to use ALTER AUTHORIZATION on the databases which have the NULL login match for dbo.

Comment: This is by far the easiest way to fix this. Saved my day :-)

Answer (score 1):

I found that if you use article filters, you must use a unique filter name. Once I changed the filter name to be unique across all articles, it fixed this issue.

Answer (score 0):

In our case the service account that the SQL instance was running on got locked. Once unlocked and we stopped/restarted the LogReader SQL agent jobs then things started flowing again.