# Stored Procedure Not Working From ASP Page

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures, merge

we are having issues with a stored procedure.  When calling it from our website via asp/vb.net it seems to not be executing properly.  If I run it from SSMS it works.

I have run the debugger when the call is being placed, the parameters being passed in are correct at the time of the ExecuteNonQuery() call but it is not generating any records in the related tables like it should.  If I use the same values seen while debugging our website directly in SSMS, the stored procedure creates the expected records.

Here is our stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CopyGoals](
@OldVisitID int,
@NewVisitID int,
@CreatedBy NVarChar(30)
) AS BEGIN
declare @GoalMapping As Table(OldGoalID int,NewGoalID int);

    Merge Into VisitGoals
Using(
    select GoalsID,Goal,ProgressNote,Progress,Completed,CreatedOn,CreatedBy,VisitID
    From VisitGoals
    Where VisitID = @OldVisitID
) As Src
On 1 = 0
When Not Matched By Target Then
Insert (Goal,ProgressNote,Completed,VisitID,Progress, CreatedOn, CreatedBy)
Values (Src.Goal, Src.ProgressNote, Src.Completed, @NewVisitID, Src.Progress, GetDate(), @CreatedBy)
Output Src.GoalsID As OldGoalID, inserted.GoalsID as NewGoalID
Into @GoalMapping;

Insert Into SubGoals(GoalID,VisitID,GoalText,HasCompleted,WillComplete,GoalStatus)
(
    Select GM.NewGoalID, @NewVisitID, SG.GoalText, SG.HasCompleted, SG.WillComplete, SG.GoalStatus
    From SubGoals As SG inner join @GoalMapping As GM on SG.GoalID = GM.OldGoalID
    Where SG.VisitID = @OldVisitID
)
END
```

Here is the procedure call from our website page:

```
    Dim conStr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionString").ConnectionString
    Dim curUsr As New Supervisor(Context.User.Identity.Name, True)

    Using con As New SqlConnection(conStr)
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("CopyGoals", con)
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@OldVisitID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = oldVID
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@NewVisitID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = newVID
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@CreatedBy", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 30).Value = curUsr.Name

            con.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            con.Close()
        End Using
    End Using
```

What this procedure should do, and does if run from SSMS, is look at our Goals table with the existing IDs matching a foreign key corresponding to the VisitID in a different table to find all goals associated with that old visit.

It them copies the goal information and inserts it into the Goals table, outputting the old goal IDs and the newly inserted goal IDs into the @GoalMapping table.

It then looks into our SubGoals table and does a similar thing by copying each subgoal related to the goals we just copied.  For whatever reason, this procedure does not execute properly when called from our page even when it runs in SSMS when we feed it the same input values as seen during debugging of the page.  There are no errors reported in chrome's debugger, we tried wrapping execute in a try with an SQL and normal exception but neither of them tripped.  We are pretty stumped.  Maybe someone will spot something we haven't over the last few days.

Here is the output from Sql Profiler:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried executing the stored procedure via SSMS using the same user which website is using? It can be a permission issue. Also, you can run SQL Profiler and then run the website and then check the T-SQL query executed by website.

Comment: check your connection string first. if it is correct, check whether your profiler execute the query.

Comment: @NijinKoderi Hi Nijin, I have done so but as far as I can tell there were no errors.  It does show 0 "writes" though, does this mean it did not insert the found (read is 7) records?

Comment: @MohsinMehmood Hi Mohsin, did as suggested.  The sp ran and the values look correct in the profiler.  No errors as far as I can tell.  I have included the profiler trace in an image on the question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I finally figured it out.  There was a permission issue as Mohsin suggested.  I logged in as the user that we use for our ASP.net connection strings and attempted to run the query in question and it failed to generate the records from SSMS.  So after some digging I found this question:

[Stored Procedure and Permissions - Is EXECUTE enough?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3815411/stored-procedure-and-permissions-is-execute-enough/3815444)

Which lead to this question when I got the same error:

[SQL Server principal "dbo" does not exist,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13823354/sql-server-principal-dbo-does-not-exist)

Combined together, the answers to these questions helped me fix the issue.