# Transactional replication errors

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, database-replication, transactional-replication

I'm trying to set up transactional replication in SQL Server 2012 using AdventureWorks 2012. And right at the end of the publications setup i get the following error:

> `SQL Server could not start the Snapshot Agent.
>   Additional Information:
>   An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch.
>   (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
>   SQL ServerAgent is not currently running so it cannot be modified of this  action.
>   Changed database context to 'AdventureWorks2012'.(Microsoft SQL Server,Error 22022)`

I'm guessing this error isn't allowing me to execute the following code:

```
USE ADRepl;
SELECT * FROM Person.BusinessEntity
```

As every time I do execute this I get the following error:

> `Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Invalid object name 'Person.BusinessEntity'.`

Comment: Did you start the SQL server agent and see if that fixes the problem? N.B. Cheers, Thanks, etc is not necessary.

Comment: That made snapshot agent start but I'm still getting the error for Person.BusinessEntity

Comment: Did you verify in SQL server studio if the table got replicated and if there were any errors? There is a replication monitor which will tell you the status and if there were any errors

Comment: The error I get is: the process could not execute 'sp_replcmds'

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723061/

Comment: Oof. No offense meant, but if you can't troubleshoot a table missing, you're not up to setting up and troubleshooting replication. Walk before you run, padawan.

Answer (score 0):

Make your sql agent property as automatic.

Answer (score 0):

Set the SQL server agent service Automatically.

- Press windows key+R
- type services.msc
- right Click on sql server agent
- properties >> startup >> select automatically.